# k8s egress network policy not working for dns

Tags: kubernetes

I have added this NetworkPolicy to block all egress but allow DNS.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: {{ $namespace }}
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          networking/namespace: kube-system
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

However, I'm getting this error with a service that this rule applies to: `Could not lookup srv records on _origintunneld._tcp.argotunnel.com: lookup _origintunneld._tcp.argotunnel.com on 10.2.0.10:53: read udp 10.32.1.179:40784->10.2.0.10:53: i/o timeout`

This IP (10.2.0.10) belongs to the kube-dns service, which has a pod with the `k8s-app=kube-dns` label and is in the kube-system namespace with the label `networking/namespace=kube-system`.

If I remove the pod selector and namespace selector then the egress policy works and I do not get the error

This works but is not secure as it isn't restricted to the kube-dns pod:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: {{ $namespace }}
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

kube-system namespace yaml: `kubectl get namespace kube-system -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-30T22:08:25Z"
  labels:
    networking/namespace: kube-system
  name: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "4084751"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system
  uid: b93e68b0-7899-4f39-a3b8-e0e12e4008ee
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active
```

Comment: What cni are you using?

Comment: I have network policy enabled on my gke cluster so I believe it is using calico

Comment: What k8s version are you using? I'll try to replicate it

Comment: 1.17.14-gke.400

Comment: Did you verify that `kube-system` namespace have that label? `kubectl get namespace kube-system -o yaml`

Comment: yes, I just added the output of that command to the question

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. For me it was because NodeLocal DNSCache was enabled on my cluster.

Comment: do you remove NodeLocal DNSCache or find another way ?

Comment: you just have to add another egress allow block that matches the "k8s-app=node-local-dns" label.

Answer (score 0):

Current policy does not explicitly allow traffic to Kubernetes DNS. As a result, DNS queries from pods in `{{ $namespace }}` will be dropped, unless allowed by other rules.

Creating an allow egress rule to k8s DNS should resolve your issue.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: {{ $namespace }}
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              networking/namespace: kube-system
          podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              k8s-app: kube-dns
      ports:
        - port: 53
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 53
          protocol: UDP
    - to:
        - namespaceSelector: {}
          podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              k8s-app: kube-dns
      ports:
        - port: 53
          protocol: UDP
```

Comment: That would only allow the kube-dns pods to egress to the dns. I need to allow all pods in a given namespace to egress to the kube-dns pods.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on GKE 1.27.3-gke.100 when I configured FQDN Network Policy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue. In my case I am using GKE Dataplane v2 Network Policies. In this scenario, Dataplane V2 is basically a managed Cillium implementation (not fully featured). It will be managing some of its internal CRD resources required to maintain a healthy network. This can lead to some conflicts with app deployment tools which automatically sync k8s resources (e.g.: ArgoCD). With proper testing I found that my network policies were not matching pod labels for "k8s-app: kube-dns".

So perhaps a quick fix for your test is to allow all pods in kube-system namespace by removing the podSelector code:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: {{ $namespace }}
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          networking/namespace: kube-system
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

If you confirm egress is working, you need to further troubleshoot your environment and understand why your netpolicy is not matching the kube-dns label.

If you are using ArgoCD a good place to start is by blacklisting/excluding cillium.io resources. For example, include this in your ArgoCD config:

```
 resource.exclusions: |
    - apiGroups:
      - cilium.io
      kinds:
      - CiliumIdentity
      - CiliumEndpoint
      clusters:
      - "*"
```